# Testing my cloudfunction using Jest and context.params.userId is undefined in onUpdate Trigger Typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, jestjs, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am writing test for my firebase cloudfunction trigger. and i followed this fireship [tutorial](https://fireship.io/lessons/testing-cloud-functions-in-firebase/) first one i write work fine in which trigger is invoked when user create an new Post, it create a new document in user document and it worked.

now i am on 2nd trigger its on userUpdate, if user update personal information that's stored in `users/GC7QEZGBfcYw1tYXyoQfbsRw8ll1`. it do many things like fetch all friends and update basic information of this user in all friends and update in posts but i am getting error that userId isn't defined that i provide in path

i don't know what i am missing.

my 2nd question : is it possible to update data in firebase emulator instead of online firebase ?

here is what i did

initializeApp

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: "firebase project ID",
    privateKey:
      "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\$Key=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    clientEmail:
      "clientEmail from firebase",
  }),
  databaseURL: "firebase database url",
});
```

```
import functions from "firebase-functions-test";
const testEnv = functions({
  databaseURL: "firebase database url",
  projectId: "firebase project id",
});
```

Test Code

```
import "jest";
describe("On Update User", () => {
  test("It update user info in all friends & Events", async () => {
    const wrapped = testEnv.wrap(onUpdateUser);
    const path = "users/GC7QEZGBfcYw1tYXyoQfbsRw8ll1";
    const data1 = {
      avatarUrl: "avatarUrl",
      bio: "bio",
      last_name_lower: "ben",
      name: "Ben",
      name_lower: "ben",
      username: "ben",
    };
    const data2 = {
      avatarUrl: "avatarUrl",
      bio: "bio",
      last_name_lower: "khan",
      name: "Khan",
      name_lower: "khan",
      username: "khan007",
    };
    const snap1 = testEnv.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot(data1, path);
    const snap2 = testEnv.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot(data2, path);
    const change = testEnv.makeChange(snap1, snap2);

    // Execute it
    await wrapped(change);

  });
});
```

i used firebase emulator to test all triggers and everything worked but using jest i am facing this issue

first error i get is

> Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string.

on `firestore.collection("friends").doc(userId)`

```
at Object.validateResourcePath (../node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/path.js:406:15)
      at CollectionReference.doc (../node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:1982:20)
      at Function.ref (models/friends.ts:44:44)
      at Function.descriptor.value (decorators/log.ts:18:31)
      at Function.fromId (models/friends.ts:33:29)
      at Function.descriptor.value (decorators/log.ts:18:31)
      at Function.exports.onUpdateUser.functions.firestore.document.onUpdate [as run] (users/onUpdateUser.ts:23:37)
      at wrapped (../node_modules/firebase-functions-test/lib/main.js:71:30)
      at Object.test (test/userUpdate.test.ts:35:11)
```

i also have used decorator to log parameters

and it log

> arg  1  is  undefined

Comment: For the first error could you try to change the double quotes to single quotes since I remember there were some causes that double quotes cannot be used as paths.

Comment: didn't worked and i am using double quotes in my other test its working

Comment: @StefanNeacsu i figured out if trigger have used context,params.userId then it say its undefined i will find solution for it in morning thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is (currently) by design and you have to pass in a ContextOptions object that includes your [wildcard params](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-test/blob/34f612ac427653adbdf6385bd8e3d3dace1ed18f/src/main.ts#L42). See [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-test/issues/10) for more info.

Something like this should work, though it's strange to have to do this extra step.

```js
// Execute it
await wrapped(after, {
  params: {
    userId: 'GC7QEZGBfcYw1tYXyoQfbsRw8ll1'
  }
});
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me - thanks whatsthatitspat